# Fixed contour display

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, contour, basler

I use the grain contour method and the openCV library to count the seeds and set them up. My camera is a Basler 1920 ace.
I use light for lighting and even increase the exposure to 50000, but when we are going to count the grains live, in a fixed container that does not move and we do not have ambient light, the number of lines and grains changes. Slowly
How can I solve this problem?
Grateful